# Switch the PNP BJT transistor

Tags: transistors, boost, converter, pnp, silicon

[image: calculations]

This is my buck/boost converter in the simulation.
I get the desired voltage of -12 V but in the real circuit I am only getting -4.88 V,
and my transistor heats up; I think it is even burned. I don't know how to turn on and off my transistor safely.

Why am I getting a higher voltage than -12 V?

My transistor is silicon PNP.

[image: the output voltage]

Comment: "P-channel" is a type of MOSFET, but your circuit uses a (PNP) BJT. Please edit your question to describe your circuit clearly.

Comment: As for why your transistor heats up, you can't just apply -3 V to the base of a BJT.

Comment: @ThePhoton why i cant do that? i am applying 3.3V from the raspberrypi

Comment: Because the base emitter junction of a BJT acts like a diode and will draw large currents if you apply more than ~0.7 V (less than -0.7 for PNP) to it.

Comment: What a switch circuit I can build to make it work ? I cant change the supply voltage

Comment: Either use a resistor to limit hase current of the PNP, or change it to a MOSFET.

Comment: all the pmosfet that i checked they have a Vgs -2 to -4 , and my raspberrypi give just 3.3V, if i want to add a resistor , where i add it ?

Comment: In series with V2, somewhere in the 100-500 ohm range (sorry, no time to calculate the ideal value).

Comment: Can you explain the control waveform in terms of frequency and duty cycle. The duty cycle which controls the transistor (yes it should have a base series resistor) has an active low part so when the control signal is low it turns on the transistor. Also, can you explain whether you think it'll work in DCM or CCM?

Comment: @Andyaka I think it work in CCM , and the frequency of PWM 70000Hz , and the duty cycle is low (0.28)

Comment: @ThePhoton Since this is a Raspberry Pi, it's output driving the BJT will probably present about \$100\:\Omega\$, anyway. It's kind of self-limiting. Not so good for the Pi's output, though. Given the power required, over a watt, there's probably a need for two BJTs here. Just skimming over this.

Comment: @SalhaShomary I'd like to see your calculations. All of them. Including ones that tell you what the CCS current in the inductor is supposed to be and how you arrived at a specific duty cycle. If you chose the frequency first, I'd like to see how you calculated the inductance. If you chose the inductance first, I'd like to see how you arrived at the frequency. I'd also like to see what you imagined as realistic values for the parasitics in the inductor.

Comment: The numbers don’t add up in the pulse statement in your diagram @SalhaShomary. You need to show the waveform and, offer the calcs that underline your circuit (as others have said).

Comment: you need to change your bias circuit, things in real-world aren't  that sweet!

Comment: i read that if i use pnp i should flip the duty cycle ,so i define a low duty cycle for pnp

Answer (score 0):

Following are the answers for the questions asked:

1. In reality, there are many parasitics involved in circuit which have not been modeled in your Pspice circuit such as inductor comes up with internal resistance(Rl), capacitor has ESR(resistance), source resistance(Rs). Although small but impact on the Voltage ratio is huge. Following graph(from some Paper) shows when you take into account the calculation of these parasitics. Ideal one as provided by you. Usually operating at high duty-ratio is not recommended because of this reason, as it does not follow the formulae correctly. Solution would be to use flyback converter(isolated buck-boost).

[image]

2. Usually when we drive any transistor(that too switch used in power converter), It is recommended not to drive the transistor directly from the micro-controller pins(It is costly). **It can damage the pin of your Raspberry Pi**. A **gate-driver circuit**(some idea given below)) should be used for the appropriate transistor.

Comments:

- MOSFET Driver: Since it acts as capacitive gate. Initial Pulse current would require a small rated transistor between controller and MOSFET
- BJT Driver: Totem-pole would suffice for that or simple n-p-n transistor also.
- While testing, check on oscilloscope the signal of gate/base of transistor. Since the signal would not be proper turn-on and turn off at such high frequency. It would be something like this(Green). (Sometime it has a slant turn-on/turn-off such that duty cycle may go up from 0.8 to 0.95). Voltage will go down further. Kindly take this into account.

[image]

- The transistor used is 2n2905 which may not be able to support 70k due to high switching losses causing your transistor to heat up.() [Stackexchange Link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171537/bipolar-junction-transistors)
  [image]